# get_current_user_id() постоянно выдает 0

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть сайт на Wordpress и файл add_events.php со следующим содержимым.
Под аккаунтом админа wordpress открываю http://localhost/wordpress/add_events.php выводит 0.
И в БД тоже вводит 0 при ajax запросе к add_events.php

```
<?php

$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];

try {
    require "db_config.php";
    require "../wp-includes/user.php";
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

echo get_current_user_id(); //debug
$cur_user_id = get_current_user_id();

$sql = "INSERT INTO events (title, start, cur_user_id) VALUES (:title, :start, :cur_user_id)";
$q = $cal_db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':cur_user_id'=>$cur_user_id));

?>
```

Я пытаюсь получить id авторизованного пользователя, но всегда возвращается 0

Kак правильно использовать get_current_user_id() ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ядро надо подключать как положено, чтобы функции wp работали: require wp-load.php.

Comment: А ещё лучше, освоить ajax в WordPress: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: при подключении wp-load.php выводится:
Warning: require(wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\calendar\add_events.php on line 9

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'wp-load.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\calendar\add_events.php on line 9

Comment: Я ж не развернутый ответ пишу, а комментарий. Путь к wp-load.php уж сам как-нибудь найди и поставь правильный.

Comment: Отличный пример как нельзя работать с ВП. Одновременно с ошибкой XY.

Comment: Я написал плагин по туториалу wp-kama.ru
все сработало, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я написал плагин по [руководству](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html), все сработало, спасибо.

Нужно было написать свой мини-плагин, потом активировать в *wordpress*.

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Plugin name: добавление событий через AJAX
     */
    
    add_action('wp_ajax_event', 'add_event');
    
    function add_event() {
        
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $start = $_POST['start'];
        $cur_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    
        try {
            require "db_config.php";
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            exit('Unable to connect to database.');
        }
    
    
        $sql = "INSERT INTO events (title, start, cur_user_id) VALUES (:title, :start, :cur_user_id)";
        $q = $cal_db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':cur_user_id'=>$cur_user_id));
    
        wp_die();
    }
    
    ?>
    
    //Ну и ajax запрос из html файла
              $.ajax({ //get user id
                url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=event',
 
                data: {
                  title: event_desc,
                  start: start
                },
                type: "POST",
                
                success: function(json) {
                  calendar.refetchEvents();
                  
                }
              });
```

Comment: Ну вот, уже похоже на WP. Работа с базой никакая, правда. Надо использовать $wpdb.